# What is the collision chance of a 128-bit hashing function if it is always fed with 256-bits of data?

Tags: hash

I mean "normal" collisions not based on any attack.

How do i calculate it?

Comment: Can you be a little more specific?

Comment: Let say
`a = md5(sha256(someval))
b = md5(sha256(otherval))`

What are the chances that a == b? why?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The relevant principle here is the [birthday attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_attack). It roughly states that for a 2<sup>n</sup> algorithm, your probably of a random collision is between any two items is 50% once you generate 2<sup>(n/2)</sup> outputs.

When looking at a hashing algorithm, the naive consideration of the algorithm is that the odds are bassed only on the last iteration. In this way, a 128 bit algorithm doesn't care if you feed it 1 bit or a million bits: your odds of collision should be the same for a given number of unique inputs (as you can obviously only input 2 different one-bit values).

Thus, the answer for a 128 bit algorithm is that it has a 50% chance of a collision occurring between any two values after 2<sup>64</sup> outputs have been created.

Comment: It is also worth noting that 2^64 is a teeny tiny fraction of the 2^128 hash space.

Comment: 2^64 is eighteen quintillion. So probably not getting a collision any time soon.

Comment: 2^64 is a high number but it's also for 50% collision probability. In practice, you'll probably want to ensure that the collision probability is lower than your total number of items. ie: you want collisions to be 1 in <however many objects you project on having>. So if you're expecting 100 billion items you ideally want your probability of collisions to be lower than 10^-11 (very far from 50%). In that case, a 128 bit hash like md5 will give you these odds for anything below roughly 2.6×10^13 items (26 trillion). Since 100 billion is below 26 trillion you're good to go. But getting close.